# How to study Mathematica as a newbie?

Tags: documentation, education

I am a somehow experienced programmer in MATLAB and Python.

I was wondering if anyone can help me with instructions and useful resources to learn Mathematica as fast as I can.

1. What are the best resources?
2. What should I study to deeply understand the concepts?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There are numerous similar questions on this site.  Use Search to find them.

Comment: [`Fast Intro for Programmers`](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/)

Comment: These questions are answered here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice

Comment: What about the book from Stephen Wolfram, the chief himself: Mathematica

Comment: Learning to program in Mathematica is really no different than learning to program in say Python or Java or any other language. You start small. Program small functions and lookup documentation and look at examples and so on.